# STM32 - Using Timer as time base source for HAL in FreeRTOS application

Tags: stm32, timer, hal-library, freertos, programming-loop

I am learning more about FreeRTOS by making a task-based program. My problem comes when initializing and configuring the HAL time sources. I read that it is necessary to choose another HW timer as time base source and leave the Systick for FreeRTOS. In this case I chose TIM10 (Basic Timer) as the HAL time source. When debugging, my program gets stuck inside the `HAL_MspInit()` to start the low-level hardware. Basically it loops between this function and the `TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler()` which contains the line `HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim10)`. I am not sure if there is problem with the low-level hardware or something related with the timer priorities, since the `system_clock()` function has not run yet at this point.

This is my setup:

- board: STM32F7508-DK
- clock freq: 120 MHz (HSE)
- Timers used: only TIM10 as time base source
- IDE: STM32CubeIDE

Also I clear all the pinout before configuring the system.

Code of the issue:

Main function where the `Hal_init()` runs:

```c
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
```

Below is the `Hal_Init()` funtion where everything runs until it gets to the `HAL_MspInit()`. I have used breakpoints but it never gets to return the `HAL_OK` value.

```c
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_Init(void)
{
  /* Configure Instruction cache through ART accelerator */ 
#if (ART_ACCLERATOR_ENABLE != 0)
   __HAL_FLASH_ART_ENABLE();
#endif /* ART_ACCLERATOR_ENABLE */

  /* Configure Flash prefetch */
#if (PREFETCH_ENABLE != 0U)
  __HAL_FLASH_PREFETCH_BUFFER_ENABLE();
#endif /* PREFETCH_ENABLE */

  /* Set Interrupt Group Priority */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_4);

  /* Use systick as time base source and configure 1ms tick (default clock after Reset is HSI) */
  HAL_InitTick(TICK_INT_PRIORITY);
  
  /* Init the low level hardware */
  HAL_MspInit();
  
  /* Return function status */
  return HAL_OK;
}
```

`HAL_TIM_HandlerIRQ()` (where it seems to get stuck). Here it runs all the events until it gets to the `/* TIM commutation event */` and returns to `HAL_MspInit()` after the first "IF" where it gets the flag... and keeps on doing the same.

```c
void HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  /* Capture compare 1 event */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC1) != RESET)
  {
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC1) != RESET)
    {
      {
        __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC1);
        htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1;

        /* Input capture event */
        if ((htim->Instance->CCMR1 & TIM_CCMR1_CC1S) != 0x00U)
        {
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
          htim->IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
#else
          HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
        }
        /* Output compare event */
        else
        {
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
          htim->OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
          htim->PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
#else
          HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
          HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
        }
        htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
      }
    }
  }
  /* Capture compare 2 event */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC2) != RESET)
  {
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC2) != RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC2);
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_2;
      /* Input capture event */
      if ((htim->Instance->CCMR1 & TIM_CCMR1_CC2S) != 0x00U)
      {
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
        htim->IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
#else
        HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
      }
      /* Output compare event */
      else
      {
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
        htim->OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        htim->PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
#else
        HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
      }
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
    }
  }
  /* Capture compare 3 event */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC3) != RESET)
  {
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC3) != RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC3);
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_3;
      /* Input capture event */
      if ((htim->Instance->CCMR2 & TIM_CCMR2_CC3S) != 0x00U)
      {
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
        htim->IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
#else
        HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
      }
      /* Output compare event */
      else
      {
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
        htim->OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        htim->PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
#else
        HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
      }
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
    }
  }
  /* Capture compare 4 event */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_CC4) != RESET)
  {
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_CC4) != RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_CC4);
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_4;
      /* Input capture event */
      if ((htim->Instance->CCMR2 & TIM_CCMR2_CC4S) != 0x00U)
      {
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
        htim->IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
#else
        HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
      }
      /* Output compare event */
      else
      {
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
        htim->OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        htim->PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
#else
        HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(htim);
        HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
      }
      htim->Channel = HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_CLEARED;
    }
  }
  /* TIM Update event */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE) != RESET)
  {
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_UPDATE) != RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_UPDATE);
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
      htim->PeriodElapsedCallback(htim);
#else
      HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
    }
  }
  /* TIM Break input event */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_BREAK) != RESET)
  {
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_BREAK) != RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_BREAK);
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
      htim->BreakCallback(htim);
#else
      HAL_TIMEx_BreakCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
    }
  }
  /* TIM Break2 input event */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_BREAK2) != RESET)
  {
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_BREAK) != RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_BREAK2);
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
      htim->Break2Callback(htim);
#else
      HAL_TIMEx_Break2Callback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
    }
  }
  /* TIM Trigger detection event */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_TRIGGER) != RESET)
  {
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_TRIGGER) != RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_IT_TRIGGER);
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
      htim->TriggerCallback(htim);
#else
      HAL_TIM_TriggerCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
    }
  }
  /* TIM commutation event */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(htim, TIM_FLAG_COM) != RESET)
  {
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(htim, TIM_IT_COM) != RESET)
    {
      __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(htim, TIM_FLAG_COM);
#if (USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
      htim->CommutationCallback(htim);
#else
      HAL_TIMEx_CommutCallback(htim);
#endif /* USE_HAL_TIM_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me understand the issue.

Comment: I think more debugging details are needed to answer this question. What do you mean with "it loops between these functions"? It's normal that your application is interrupted by an interrupt routine (`TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler`). Execution should continue where it left after the interrupt routine is finished. Are you saying it doesn't? Is the `HAL_MspInit()` function **started** multiple times? If so, I'd suggest to check (and increase) your stack size. If not, then I don't understand the problem. If the end of `HAL_MspInit()` is not reached, then where is it stuck?

Comment: NB: Always debug the "Debug" version of your application, i.e., with optimizations disabled. Otherwise stepping through the code may be very confusing.

Comment: I think the following thread answers your question. It looks like a bug in the generated code. https://community.st.com/t5/embedded-software-mpus/hal-tick-does-not-get-incremented-on-second-debug-session-after/m-p/259440#M2534